# Expanding ubuntu partition with unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a dual boot with windows 8 and ubuntu 16 on my laptop. I have 20gb for my ubuntu which I want to expand. I just unallocated 200gb of my windows partition via windows disk management. I booted again ubuntu with my usb drive without installing and tried Gparted to resize/move my ubuntu partition. But I can't expand ubuntu partition at all. This is what I get in Gparted:

[image: GParted screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only grow partitions if there is *adjacent* unallocated space. If you have unallocated space at a different location, you need to move all the partitions in between the two first. GParted offers a "move" operation. Moving large partitions may take a long time.

As with most operations that change the geometry of a partition, there's a significant chance of failure and data loss. So back up your data.

Comment: Thanks very much, I just moved my windows c drive to replace it with unallocated space so the unallocated space will be next to my sda3 partition. Fingers crossed I hope my system works after this!